# How to do a terms query on @Query in SpringBoot Elasticsearch Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

From [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query), an example of how to query something `IN` a list, but the example is idealized. It queries `id`.
I want to do a query: name in ["abc","ghi"]

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138821/how-to-use-terms-query-in-custom-elastic-search-query-java), I find an answer, but I find it not work.

I try several different ways below.

```
@Query("{ \"terms\": {\"name\": [\"?0\"] } }")  //the 1st query. 
Flux<Response> findByNames(String names);


@Query("{\"names\": {\"values\": ?0 }}")  //mimic the ids query in the example.
Flux<Response> findByNames(List<String> names);


@Query("{ \"terms\": {\"name\": ?0 } }")
Flux<Response> findByNames(List<String> names);
```

The 1st query, I pass in `nameList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`, it generates the query json is nearly correct, but a slight error:

```
{ "terms": {"name": ["abc,ghi"] } }
```

If it can generate the query json like ( look at the quote mark):

```
{ "terms": {"name": ["abc","ghi"] } }
```

then, it works.

So, My question is: How to do a terms query on the @Query in SpringBoot Elasticsearch Repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the handling of collection parameters in `@Query` methods that was fixed 2 weeks ago in the *main* branch (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/2182), I'll need to port that back to the currently maintained branches as well.

Addition 16.07.2022: it's backported now and will bei in the next maintenance releases of 4.4 and 4.3.